# Terraria: No Corruption!

Tags: terraria-mobile

In Terraria (Mobile), the guide is talking to me so my next step should be to destroy a Shadow Orb. Since I have the Crimson, i don't have the Shadow Orb, and according to the Wiki,

> Pulsing Hearts in the Crimson act the same as Shadow Orbs in the Corruption.

Well, I did destroy like 9 hearts and killed 3 Brains of Cthulhu, but the guide is still idle in the same two messages. I did destroy the Skeletron, I have a big village and I am almost ready for the Wall of Flesh. I don't want the Guide's missions to be still stuck on the second task.

Comment: Wow. I always wanted to get crimson in terraria mobile. But for each try the world was corruption.

Comment: I think a lot of the guide's dialogue on mobile is outdated. I'll do some looking later and post an answer if I find more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide always glitches out. I'm on my way to the mechanical bosses and he's still telling me to look for shadow orbs in the corruption. I don't have the corruption either.